# NIST statistic tests suit for randomness

Tags: c, random, cryptography, statistics

I am doing an MSc project in cryptography and trying to test if a certain random/pseudorandom number generator is "correctly" random or not.

Well, in my reasearch I found the NIST test suite for validation of random number and pseudorandom number generator and I think it is probably the best package of tests for pseudorandom numbers.

I run the tests in Linux system running gcc. I was able to run the program, but I cannot understand really well which parameters the ./assess  needs. I tried to replicate their results for the binary expansion of Pi but I just could not do it.

I ran all the tests, like they did on appendix B. I put 1000000 in sequenceLength and 1 on "how many bitstreams?" but the results were not similar. I tried to put 10 bitstreams and it gave me core dump.

Could you please give me the instructions how I can do it?

I will appreciate any help! Thank you!!!

For documentation and code: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/documentation_software.html

Comment: An alternative is to install `rngtools`.  For example, `sudo apt-get install rng-tools`.  Then pipe your random data into the program `rngtest`.  E.g., `rngtest -c 1000 < /dev/urandom`.  It should run all the statistical tests you need.

Comment: What are the statistical tests that it runs?

Comment: You can see sample output in this question:  http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71001/how-negative-are-virtual-machines-vms-to-dev-urandom.  It's trivial to install and run.